# Copy text strting from one String to another using GREP or SED using unix command line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, grep

I am new to command line scripting. I just want to copy text starting from a particular string and ending with another string. How can I achieive that using sed or grep or any other way.

eg:

```
-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
Assets/Editor/AutoBuild1.cs(12,16): error CS1001: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting identifier
Assets/Editor/AutoBuild1.cs(12,32): error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting `)'
Assets/Editor/AutoBuild1.cs(12,78): error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting `)'
Assets/Editor/AutoBuild1.cs(12,99): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting `;' or `}'
Assets/Editor/AutoBuild1.cs(12,125): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `;' or `}'
-----EndCompilerOutput---------------
```

Here I want to copy text from `-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------` till `-----EndCompilerOutput---------------` from the error log which is saved to `log.txt`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following simple `sed` may help you in same.

```
sed -n '/CompilerOutput:-stderr/,/EndCompilerOutput/p' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `sed` here with `-n` option which will STOP by default printing of the lines. Then by doing `/CompilerOutput:-stderr/,/EndCompilerOutput/` this I am searching strings on a line from string `/CompilerOutput:-stderr` to `EndCompilerOutput` if this condition is TRUE then using `p` option will print those lines then.

Comment: great its working. thanks

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: There are lot of similar questions on this nature! Why would you want to answer a known dupe?

Comment: @Inian, Apologies here, I didn't search it.